# cycle plugin with sliding pager?

Tags: jquery, cycle, jcarousel

I have a working cycle script with 6 slides, with the pager fitting perfectly across. If I added more slides how do I get the pager to slide with the current slide, and use that for the arrows (prev/next)?
Is this a feature of the [jquery cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)? Or do I need to combine it with another?

Comment: Thank you for asking my question. I'm trying to find the terminology for this effect...been browsing plugins but haven't found it yet... Seen the effect in Flash. If you know of a live site, link to it, maybe we can figure it out by viewing source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this script that does the job.

http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/